# Python: Modifying contents of <a> elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have a web page I'm scraping and parsing, using Beautiful Soup. On this webpage there are several refernces to other sources. They look a lot like this:`

```
Shakespeare wrote good, such as in <a href="link_to_source">Romeo and Juliet, IV:ii</a>.
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
Shakespeare wrote good, such as in (Romeo and Juliet, IV:ii).
```

Bare in mind, that this is a very long webpage with many lines and I need to combine all of them, so just modifying one "a" tag won't work for me, I need to modify all "a" tags on the page.

This is something I've tried already:

```
piska_ps = url_to_soup('https://he.wikisource.org'+a['href']).find_all('p')
    p_box = []
    for p in piska_ps:
        if p.a:
            for a_link in p.a:
                a_link.string = "("+a_link.string+")"
```

Comment: I tried re.sub on the webpage and for loops with a tags, subbing tag.string, but met no success...

Comment: Add the code that you used (specifically the part using beautifulsoup)

Comment: if p.a:
                for a_link in p.a:
                    a_link.string = "("+a_link.string+")"

Comment: @EsterLin next time use `@dekel`, otherwise I will not get a notification :)

Comment: can you provide a real link to check on? (what is `a['href']`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `replace_with` to replace a tag:

```
piska_ps = url_to_soup('https://he.wikisource.org'+a['href']).find_all('p')
for p in piska_ps:
    for a in p.find_all('a'):
        a.replace_with("(" + a.string + ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `p.a` is equal to `p.find('a')`, which return one tag, you can not iterate over it.

```
piska_ps = url_to_soup('https://he.wikisource.org'+a['href']).find_all('p')
p_box = []
    for p in piska_ps:
        if p.a:
            p.a.string = "("+p.a.string+")"
```